# dynamic SQL compare two rows inside any Oracle SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, dynamic-sql

I have a few hundred history tables, some hundreds of columns wide,  and I am looking to be able to find two rows and check which columns are different.

each table in question has an Id column that is a single autoincrementing integer
and each table in question doesn't have any crazy datatypes

can I use dynamic SQL to write a generic function that will compare two rows inside any SQL Table

inputs: "table_name", "id1", "id2"

```
  desired outputs: 
  Column_Name,   id1_Value,  id2_Value
```

i've started by querying the metadata from all_user_cols but now i'm not exactly sure how to proceed. Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: Check out Stew Ashton's Compare and Sync utility.  It's a nice wrapper for such a task

https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/comp_sync-1-a-new-table-compare-sync-package/

Comment: Do both tables have same structure (same columns) ? How would you compare two specific table rows without dynamic query - give an example pls.

Comment: Can you please share three sample example tables with sample data along with the output you are looking for?